# Dependency management on tomcat server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a java web application which is deployed on several servers. The project uses maven dependency management tool.

The war file that is created after including all the dependencies is quite large. If I use scope "provided" for all dependencies, the war fail created is quite small. I want to use the latter war file for deployment and manage dependencies on the remote servers itself.

I can add a folder containing those dependencies to all the servers and include it in the tomcat class path but if in future I add another dependency I will have to add that dependency to all the servers. Please suggest a workaround.

Comment: There isn't one. Adding webapp dependencies to Tomcat's classpath is a sure fire way to cause unexpected and difficult to diagnose bugs. Use the large war.

Comment: @BoristheSpider will including those dependencies in a shared lib folder create problems too?

Comment: @user1460261 the libraries of an application should be in the war of this appication, not outside. And that's the easiest way to deploy a new version anyway. What do you gain by being forced to deploy a war, and a directory containing the dependencies of this war, rather than simply deploying the war?

Comment: With dependencies the WAR size is around 30 MB and without them it is  500 KB. Also, dependencies don't change that often. This will reduce deployment  time.