# Managing multiple versions of a project dependency on Tomcat using Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am using Tomcat server and I've got multiple versions of a product that is built on Maven, they are using almost same library.

How can I centralize the library of all versions in one place, when I do
 not want to place that library in the Tomcat 'lib' folder?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087372/dependency-management-on-tomcat-server?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Maven itself has a concept of centralized repository. Use can specify the location of centralized repository in settings.xml file of maven.